# Вставка содержимого компонента TextBox в закладку в документе MS Word посредством Visual Studio С++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, ms-word, office

Имеется шаблон Word (расширение .dot), содержащий в себе текст и закладки (у каждой, разумеется, есть свое имя) в определенных местах этого текста. Шаблон нужно открыть и на место закладок вставить данные (например ФИО, дату или адрес), которые пользователь вводит в компоненты TextBox на форме(приложение WindowsForms) и сохранить файл с расширением .doc. С++ начал изучать не так давно, поэтому прошу помочь в написании этого фрагмента кода

Comment: Открывайте MSDN, находите там word.application и изучаете справку. Например вот http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244391.aspx

Comment: Не путайте C++ и C++/CLI - это _разные_ языки. Используя WinForms, вы пишете на последнем. Если вы хотите изучить именно C++, то забудьте про WinForms. А лучше вообще не используйте Visual Studio (именно потому, что она позволяет писать на обоих языках).

Comment: Вот с топ 10 гугла ссылка http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread621497.html - пробуйте.